# Line Charts in JS: A label for each data point

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot, flot

We want to have line charts generated from our data where each of our data points should have a label. We tried this with [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) and [jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/) already but without success.

Do you know a way to do this with one of these libraries or maybe an other JS / jQuery library that is able to do this?

Comment: Highcharts? http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-labels

Comment: Your question is far too vague, what have your tried exactly ? Provide some code!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan We already had a look on Highcharts, but it is simply too expensive for us. :)

Comment: @Giann In jqplot we tried to put `pointLabels: {show: true, location: 'e', edgeTolerance: -15}` into the seriesDefaults, analog to the bar charts.

Comment: This is far too vague; it's not even clear what you mean by points having a label.

Comment: @DNS We want to have something like Rory [posted](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-labels). Flot and jqplot only let us plot the lines or even the points. But we didn't find options to label those points.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flot Data Labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174298/flot-data-labels)

Comment: @DNS Thanks for the help. Exactly what we wanted! :)

Comment: How hard were you trying, jqplot does this out of the box: http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/point-labels.html